# Optimal probability distribution with no knowledge about the base rates

Tags: distributions, bayesian

If we have absolutely no knowledge about the base rates (maybe except for the number of possible outcomes), what is the most accurate probability distribution to assume, is it uniform?

Here is a practical example. I don't know whether the Universe is real or I am just living in a simulation. In either case, my observations would be exactly the same. Furthermore, I haven't got the slightest clue (let's assume for the sake of the question that I don't) about the probability of the existence of a simulation, or the probability of the existence of a universe like ours, or the number of each. Also, a simulation does not necessarily have to occur in a universe with the same physical laws - as far as I know, in the underlying universe even the laws of logic might be so different that 1 + 1 equals 3.

Note that this question is not about philosophy, it is about the probabilities.

Comment: What on earth does the word 'accurate' mean in this case?

Comment: If we take a huge or infinite number of situations with no knowledge about the base rates, and check the outcome of each, our probability distribution must come as close as possible to the average number of times any particular outcome has happened.

But if Example A gave result 1 (possible results: 1, 2) and Example B gave result 45 (possible results: 26, 45), what is the average? Well, the approach must identify elements by something (e.g. size). Elements must be identifiable before the outcome is known. 

The distribution must then maximize sum of estimates for the correct outcome.

Comment: I think what you are after is the idea of an [uninformative prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Uninformative_priors).

Comment: If you have no idea of the probability of anything, then you can't have any idea about the accuracy of a distribution modeling that probability.  It seems to me this *is* about philosophy

Comment: The lack of prior information does not imply the outcome not observable. Using the observation, one can then check the accuracy of your model. However, they might need an optimal prediction before they have any data. This paper is an excellent answer to my question: http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/brandeis.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want the Principle of Maximum Entropy ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy); the article is worth reading). According to this principle, you should indeed choose the uniform distribution if you have absolutely no knowledge. But if there are some constraints which have to be satisfied, then the principle might lead to some other distribution, for example the Boltzmann distribution of statistical mechanics.

One example of the principle being applied in statistics is the (fairly popular) [exponential random graph model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_random_graph_models).

Comment: That makes sense, but how does one consistently define a model for that? I might as well ask myself whether A) I'm not living in a simulation B) I'm living in a simulation and the creatures simulating me have eyes C) same as B), but they have no eyes. This gives 2/3 for simulation, doesn't it?

Comment: I am a bit murky on this at the moment, but I think that in this case "living in a simulation" is not independent of "creatures have eyes", and you have to take that into account when finding the maximum entropy distribution. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference for example.